# com.spotify/dockerfile-maven-plugin: tag failed: path is 'null'

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, dockerfile-maven-plugin

For a multimodule maven project build using com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin on a CI runner, building the docker image with `dockerfile:build dockerfile:tag` in a previous step, and running `mvn clean deploy dockerfile:push` in deploy step results in an error:

```
Failed to execute goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-
plugin:VERSION:tag (default-cli) on project PROJECT_NAME: Execution 
default-cli of goal com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:VERSION:tag 
failed: path is 'null'.
```

Logs:

`Tagging image null as REPO_NAME/IMAGE_NAME`

Evidently, the built image isn't getting tagged properly. 
`pom.xml`:

```
                <configuration>
                    <repository>${prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
                    <tag>${tag}</tag>
                    <buildArgs>
                      <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                    </buildArgs>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
```

But I can't really find what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Running `docker image list` on the CI runner after the supposed build and tag step revealed that no image was built or tagged. Missing image causes the above error, which isn't really documented on the searchable internet.

The build step for the CI showed completed successfully, but no `mvn clean package dockerfile:build` was called (because of a hidden condition).

Probably too specific of a resolution to help anybody else, but at least the error message is out there in the internet now.

Comment: Yup, seems like this message appears when the image is not built. Thanks for filing this!